# SQLITE WITH CLAUSE using date type

Tags: sql, sqlite, date

How can I list the next 10 months from one date?

Something like that:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(x) AS (VALUES(date('2014-01-01')) UNION ALL SELECT date('2014-01-01','+1 month') FROM cnt WHERE x < date('2014-01-01','+10 month'))
SELECT x FROM cnt;
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

This works!!!

Sorry guys!

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(x) AS (VALUES(date('2014-01-01')) UNION ALL SELECT date(x,'+1 month') FROM cnt WHERE x < date('2014-01-01','+10 month'))
SELECT x FROM cnt;
```